WordPress how to use wp_localize_script()
I have trouble localizing PHP variables for use in JS in WP.
I have a plugin I'm working on, which has several scripts that I enqueue with wp_enqueue_scripts() (suppose the handle I gave it is 'my_script'), which works as intended.
However, on one page I would like to submit a value (a counter in a foreach loop, which might change) from PHP to JS and I am unclear how to properly do this.
Assume I have this in my_page.php which is a submenu page in my plugin:

$my_counter = get_my_count();

    wp_localize_script(
        'my_script',
        'my_js_object',
        array(
            'ajax_url' => $ajax_url,
            'my_counter' => $my_counter
        )
    );

and my JS in my_script.js:
console.log(my_js_object.my_counter);

From what I understand, my_script points to the JS-file I enqueued in functions.php. However, this isn't working, and my console tells me 'my_js_object' is not defined.
What do I localize where to get this to work?

May be this can help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306711/how-to-use-wp-localize-script-in-custom-page-template

Enqueue and localise scripts.php:
function my_enqueue_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/myscript.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'my_script_object',
        array( 
            'example_data' => 'Hello!',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );

Use localised variables in myscript.js:
console.log( my_script_object.example_data );

